# Cannot read property 'targetNum' of undefined

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to go through the sample-Groceries tutorial and everything goes fine on iOS platform but when I try `tns run android --emulator` I get a `Cannot read property 'targetNum' of undefined` error message.

If I do `./gradlew buildapk --debug` I get these lines with errors:

```
23:35:07.082 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :processDebugResources FAILED
23:35:07.083 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :processDebugResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.45 secs.
23:35:07.083 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 1.491 secs, idle: 0.011 secs
23:35:07.089 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:35:07.090 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:35:07.090 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:35:07.090 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:35:07.090 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
23:35:07.090 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
23:35:07.091 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:35:07.091 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
23:35:07.091 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
23:35:07.092 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
23:35:07.092 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

I already run `tns doctor` and verified `ANDROID_HOME` variable.  Also upgraded to the latest core modules and tried with a few cocoapods versions because tns doctor keeps sending me warnings about a bad CocoaPods installation.

EDIT:  Thank you @dennis for finding a solution.  It is there but I missed that big light blue warning box:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up an Android Virtual Device (AVD)? Chances are it's giving that error because there's no Android emulator to connect to. I was able to reproduce the error with a fresh repo with no AVD configured, but after I set one up `tns run android --emulator` worked smoothly.

If you don't have a AVD setup, you can use Android Studio and this guide to get up and running: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Comment: Thank you very much Dennis.  I was going to blame Telerik's documentation for not including this on their tutorial but then I double checked and notice a big light blue warning there.

Comment: @zJorge glad you got it sorted!